# batch size does not work for caffe with deploy.prototxt

Tags: neural-network, classification, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to make my classification process a bit faster. I thought of increasing the first input_dim in my deploy.prototxt but that does not seem to work. It's even a little bit slower than classifying each image one by one.

deploy.prototxt

```
input: "data"  
input_dim: 128  
input_dim: 1  
input_dim: 120  
input_dim: 160  
... net description ...
```

python net initialization

```
net=caffe.Net( 'deploy.prototxt', 'model.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
net.blobs['data'].reshape(128, 1, 120, 160)
transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data':net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
#transformer settings
```

python classification

```
images=[None]*128
for i in range(len(images)):
  images[i]=caffe.io.load_image('image_path', False)
for j in range(len(images)):
  net.blobs['data'].data[j,:,:,:] = transformer.preprocess('data',images[j])
out = net.forward()['prob']
```

I skipped some details, but the important stuff should be given. I tried different batch size, like 32, 64, ..., 1024 but all nearly the same. So my question is, if someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong or what needs to be changed?
Thanks for help!

EDIT:
Some timing results, the avg-times are just the total-times devided by the processed images(1044).

Batch size: 1

> 2016-05-04 10:51:20,721 - detector - INFO - data shape: (1, 1, 120, 160)
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - GPU timings:
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - processed images: 1044
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - total-time: 14.43s
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - avg-time: 13.82ms
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - load-time: 8.31s
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - avg-load-time: 7.96ms
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - classify-time: 5.99s
>   2016-05-04 10:51:35,149 - **main** - INFO - avg-classify-time: 5.74ms

Batch size: 32

> 2016-05-04 10:52:30,773 - detector - INFO - data shape: (32, 1, 120, 160)
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,135 - **main** - INFO - GPU timings:
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,135 - **main** - INFO - processed images: 1044
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,135 - **main** - INFO - total-time: 14.36s
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,136 - **main** - INFO - avg-time: 13.76ms
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,136 - **main** - INFO - load-time: 7.13s
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,136 - **main** - INFO - avg-load-time: 6.83ms
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,136 - **main** - INFO - classify-time: 7.13s
>   2016-05-04 10:52:45,136 - **main** - INFO - avg-classify-time: 6.83ms

Batch size: 128

> 2016-05-04 10:53:17,478 - detector - INFO - data shape: (128, 1, 120, 160)
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - GPU timings:
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - processed images: 1044
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - total-time: 13.82s
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - avg-time: 13.24ms
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - load-time: 7.06s
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - avg-load-time: 6.77ms
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - classify-time: 6.66s
>   2016-05-04 10:53:31,299 - **main** - INFO - avg-classify-time: 6.38ms

Batch size: 1024

> 2016-05-04 10:54:11,546 - detector - INFO - data shape: (1024, 1, 120, 160)
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - GPU timings:
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - processed images: 1044
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - total-time: 13.77s
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - avg-time: 13.19ms
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - load-time: 7.04s
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - avg-load-time: 6.75ms
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - classify-time: 6.63s
>   2016-05-04 10:54:25,316 - **main** - INFO - avg-classify-time: 6.35ms

Comment: are you using GPU or CPU?

Comment: I'm using GPU: nvidia GTX980 Ti

Comment: what do you mean by "all nearly the same"? the runtime of `net.forward()` is the same regardless of `batch_size`, or the runtime *divided* by `batch_size` is "nearly the same"? can you put some numbers here?

Comment: After a  specific batch size, say 32, the forward time will become almost constant. This is happen as the GPU is fully utilized. If you keep increasing, you will reach a point where you fall short of memory requirement. It is much better to post results.

Comment: I added some timing results.

Comment: It seems nobody really know how to handle that in python. I thought of making a caffe database with 'convert_imageset' tool but I don't know how to use that with finer control than the train tool. I need access to the output for every single image.  
But I don't know how to start single batches with python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in line

```
for j in range(len(images)):
net.blobs['data'].data[j,:,:,:] =   transformer.preprocess('data',images[j])
out = net.forward()['prob']
```

Doing this will simply set the single image data from the last iteration of the for loop as the network's only input. Try stacking the `N` images (say `stackedimages`) beforehand and calling the line only once e.g

```
for j in range(len(images)):
stackedimages <- transformer.preprocess('data',images[j])
```

Then call,

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] =   stackedimages
```

Comment: I don't think this is an issue. at each iteration a different slice of `['data'].data` is set, and the `forward()` is called only after all slices were assigned.

Comment: I'm with @Shai. In `['data'].data` each index j should have the appropriatly transformed image at the end of the for loop.  
Nevertheless I have a question: what is the needed data structure for `stackedimages`? Atm all the images are in a list, but a change would be possible. Or would `net.blobs['data'].data[...] = images` be possible?

Comment: Ahh yes, I see. you are right. `net.blobs['data'].data[...] = images` would work fine if the `images` are all already transformed. Just make sure they are appropriately stacked to form the 4d blob of the same dimensions