# Caffe Batch processing no speedup

Tags: c++, deep-learning, benchmarking, caffe

I would like to speedup the forward pass of classification of a CNN using caffe.

I have tried batch classification in Caffe using code provided in here:
[Modifying the Caffe C++ prediction code for multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668699/modifying-the-caffe-c-prediction-code-for-multiple-inputs)
This solution enables me to give a vector of Mat, but it does not speed up anything. Even though the input layer is modified.

I am processing pretty small images (3x64x64) on a powerful pc with two GTX1080, and there is no issue in terms of memory.
I tried also changing the deploy.prototxt, but I get the same result.

It seems that at one point the forward pass of the CNN becomes sequential. 
I have seen someone pointing this out here also:
[Batch processing mode in Caffe - no performance gains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522469/batch-processing-mode-in-caffe-no-performance-gains)

Another similar thread, for python : [batch size does not work for caffe with deploy.prototxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003575/batch-size-does-not-work-for-caffe-with-deploy-prototxt?rq=1)

I have seen some things about MemoryDataLayer, but I am not sure this will solve my problem.

So I am kind of lost on what to do exactly... does anyone have any information on how to speedup classification time.
Thanks for any help !

Comment: are you sure you are in GPU mode?

Comment: Hello,Yes I checked this as best I could. When using the Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::CPU) the processing time is muuuuuuuuch longer, there is also more activity on the CPU. When using the Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::GPU) I can see some activity on the GPU and the processing time is decreased by a large margin. Although it still seems underwhelming, I am using at most 20% of my GPU with roughly 650 Mb Ram used out of 8Gb... So I am wondering if I should do some magick Cuda trick or whatever to preload the images in memory...

Comment: Hi @HnT, do you find any solution for this problem?